# Adding a Calendar plugin into MVC 5 / Bootstrap 3, not sure how to import files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, fullcalendar

I am looking to add a calendar plugin and I found two that both demo nicely however I have no idea how to import them into my project.

I have been able to import small plugins that only include a `js` and `css` file/folder, but both of these plugins have a ton more files. I am still new to MVC and Bootstrap, let alone Visual Studio, so I do not know how to install all of the other files/folders.

Could someone give me some basic instructions please?

The two calenders I am looking at are (would like to use option two if possible)

- [FullCalendar](http://www.jplugins.net/fullcalendar/?demo)
- [Bootstrap-Calendar](https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar)

Going off of option two, I would "guess" that I would drag and drop all of the folders and .css files into Content, then put the .js within the Scripts folder, but I have no clue what to do with everything else. I am paranoid about breaking my project, thus why I would like some guidance please.

Image of files in Bootstrap-Calendar, for reference.

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: At the second link scroll down and read through "quick setup". That seems to answer your question.

Comment: holy facepalm. Am I stupid or what. >.> Thanks mate.

Comment: I believe full calendar has a nuget package so you don't have to drag anything anywhere.

Comment: It is not full calendar. It is bootstrap-calendar and have no nuget package.

Comment: @SergeyRomanov It uses all the fullcalendar properties and setups..?

Comment: @Austin no it is completely different component.

Comment: @SergeyRomanov Really? To modify items within fullcalendar though I used all of the **[fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)** site information and the source looked exactly the same. Did bootstrap rip it off? Cause the source looks exactly the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for an answer. (using FullCalendar 1.6.4)

**[FullCalendar Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4qr5a/)**

First I went to *Manage NuGet Manager* in the Solution and installed the FullCalendar Plugin.

Then I stuck it into the View like the following.

*NOTE: Be sure to update the two `link href` and the `@RenderScripts` for the location of the two **fullcalendar.css** and single **fullcalendar.js** files that installed with the FullCalendar Plugin.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<style>
    body 
    {
        margin-top: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande";
    }   
    #calendar 
    {
        width: 75%;
        height: 65%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: whitesmoke;
    }
</style>

<link href='/Content/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' /> //UPDATE YOUR PATH
<link href='/Content/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' /> //UPDATE YOUR PATH

<div id='calendar'></div>

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js") //UPDATE YOUR PATH
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Events.js") //You could put this in the View if you want.
```

**Events.js**

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month'
        },
        defaultDate: 'new Date()',
        editable: true,
        events:
            [
            {
                title: 'Bi-weekly Meeting',
                start: '2014-07-09',
                color: 'red'
            },
            {
                title: 'Tournament',
                start: '2014-07-07',
                end: '2014-07-10',
                color: 'darkorange'
            },
            {
                title: 'Test Event',
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                start: '2014-07-28'
            }
            ]
});
```